# Jquery: how to use the existing input text value without using on interaction like "change", "keyup"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

here is the jquery code that be use to display the output.. but i am using existing value in input text.
Because of that, the data can display, but I need to click the textbox and change inside the textbox to display item from database.

i dont want to change the textbox value.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.search-box2 input[type="text"]').on("keyup input", function(){
        /* Get input value on change */
        var inputVal2 = $(this).val();
        var resultDropdown2 = $(this).siblings(".result2");
        if(inputVal2.length){
            $.get("ajax2.php", {term: inputVal2}).done(function(data){
                // Display the returned data in browser
                resultDropdown2.html(data);
            });
        } else{
            resultDropdown2.empty();
        }
    });
```

Comment: `let X = $(inputSelector).val();`

Comment: `$('.search-box2 input[type="text"]').triggerHandler('input');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     const val = $('.search-box2 input[type="text"]').val();
     $.get("ajax2.php", {term: val}).done(function(data){
                // Display the returned data in browser
                resultDropdown2.html(data);
          });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just query the input any time you want and get its value through the `value` property:

```js
// VanillaJS™ variant
const value = document.querySelector('.search-box2 input[type="text"]').value;

// jQuery variant
var value = $('.search-box2 input[type="text"]').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  yourFunctionName(); /* calling function at first time */

  $('.search-box2 input[type="text"]').on("keyup input", yourFunctionName);
  // keyup and input will call the same function as well.

  function yourFunctionName() {
    //...   
  }
});
```

Note: `yourFunctionName` — it's just a variable, which contains the function code. `yourFunctionName()` - with parenthesis = meaning "run the function".